# Display Azure devops Dashboard on sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint, azure-devops

Just checking if there is a way to display whole Azure devops dashboard on sharepoint page as an image.

Not many in our organisation have access to Azure devops but we as project team want the dashboard to be visible to members who dont have access via sharepoint page.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

regards

Answer (score 1):

> Just checking if there is a way to display whole Azure devops dashboard on sharepoint page as an image.

I am afraid there isn't any option/way to do this at this moment. A similar feature request has been submitted in Visual Studio User Voice and you can vote it here:

[Embed Dashboard Widgets outside of VSTS / TFS](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365549/embed-dashboard-widgets-outside-of-vsts-tfs.html)

Hope this helps.